# jQuery datepicker not showing next years dates

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker, calendar

I'm trying to show a list of start dates but for some reason my function only seems to show dates from this year and not any from 2016. I've added the code below along with a jsfiddle link. Any help with this would be great, I've been looking everywhere on how to get this to work but have found anything that can help with next years dates.

HTML

```
<div id="date"></div>
```

jQuery

```
var availableDates = ["25-12-2015", "02-01-2016"];

function available(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
    return [true, "", "Available"];
  } else {
    return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
  }
  console.log(dmy, availableDates);
}

var lastDate = new Date("2016-10-31");  

$('#date').datepicker({
  dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
  firstDay: 1,
  beforeShowDay: available,
  minDate: "-0M",
  maxDate: lastDate
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huddds/CxNNh/2650/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `getDate()` for the 2nd would return `2` instead of `02`. And the same with `getMonth()`.

Either change your `availableDates` to:-

```
var availableDates = ["25-12-2015", "2-1-2016"];
```

or replace `dmy` like so:-

```
dmy = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CxNNh/2652/)